# Spark streaming: nested lazy transformation and actions executed non sequentially?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, lazy-evaluation

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
JavaDStream<String> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...)

stream.transform(rdd -> {
  log("Action phase 1")

  // transformation logic, really fast
  return transform(rdd);

}).forEachRDD(javaRDD -> {

  log("Action phase 2")
  // mapping functions with a relatively long processing delay, 
  // this will lead to some number of queued batches
  mapRdd(javaRDD);

})
```

And as I trail the logs, we noticed that "Action phase 1" appeared in logs multiple times (times proportionate to the number of batches queued), while "Action phase 2" only appear once per processed batch. It seems that the "lazy" transformation of `stream.transform()` is executed eagerly relatively to the RDD transformations.

My current theory is that Rdd transformations inside of the stream is also executed lazily, and with regard to the stream. Thus it is a lazy transformation inside of lazy transformation, thus the "outer" transformation is eager when compared to the internal transformation.

Is this theory correct? Or is it something else at work here?

Thanks in advance!